# ProjectOxford Emotion

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I have been trying to use the Emotion detection algorithms for Microsoft Project Oxford. However, I get a client exception telling me the image is too big or too small.

Where can I find the documentation that tells me what dimensions to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/56f23eb019845524ec61c4d7)

> JPEG, PNG, GIF(the first frame), and BMP are supported. The image file
>   size should be larger than or equal to 1KB but no larger than 4MB.
>
> The detectable face size is between 36x36 to 4096x4096 pixels. The
>   faces out of this range will not be detected.

So you need a picture that is between 1KB and 4MB in size and 36x36 to 4096x4096 in resolution.

Comment: That is actually for the Face API. Does it apply to the Emotion API as well? I actually am using a 640*480 image (or something like that) and it is around 20 KB big. Also, why throw an exception?

Comment: The limits are the same for the [Emotion API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa).  Can you check you're *not* using chunked transfer?  Neither API support it.  If you can trace your HTTP request, look for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Comment: They are indeed the same, I changed the api reference to the emotion api.

Comment: Turns out I actually made a mistake in using Blobs/Streams which resulted in a not actually open stream being sent to the API. It's working fine now.